# Is this an accurate limit proof for sine?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} \frac x{1 + \sin^2(x)} = 0$ proof

$$\left|\frac x{1 + \sin^2(x)}\right| < \epsilon$$

$$|x| < \delta$$

Let's require $|x| < 1$ so therefore,

$$\sin^2(|x|) + 1 < \sin^2(1) + 1$$

Therefore we get,

$$\frac{|x|}{|1+ \sin^2(x)|} < \frac\delta{\sin^2(1) + 1}$$

We must require,

$$\epsilon = \frac\delta{\sin^2(1) + 1}$$

Therefore, $\delta = \epsilon (\sin^2(1) + 1)$ BUT WE MUST CONSIDER $|x| < 1$ so finally,

$$\delta = \min(1, \epsilon(\sin^2(1) + 1))$$

Correct?

thanks!

Comment: why do you want $|x|<1$??

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik, it makes it easier to deal with the inequality

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be asserting that

$$\sin^2(|x|) + 1 < \sin^2(1) + 1$$

implies that

$$\frac{1}{|1+ \sin^2(x)|} < \frac 1{\sin^2(1) + 1}$$

when in fact the opposite is true.
But it is certainly true that $\sin^2(|x|) + 1 \geq 1.$
This enables you to write a very useful inequality comparing
$\left|\frac{x}{1 + \sin^2 x}\right|$ and $|x|$.

Comment: I have **never** pointed that out, never. Where did you get this?

Comment: @Amad27, how do you deduce that $\frac{|x|}{|1+ \sin^2(x)|} < \frac\delta{\sin^2(1) + 1}$?

Comment: unfortunately, I used the incorrect inequality, a < b and c < d therefore a/c < b/d. But why is this inequality invalid? I asked here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/993801/is-this-an-inequality-law-with-division/993810#993810

Comment: @Amad27, if $0<c<d$ implied that $\frac 1c < \frac 1d,$ then your statement about $a,b,c,d$ would be correct. In fact, the only way for $\frac ac < \frac bd$ to be true for all cases of $0<a<b$ is if $\frac 1c \leq \frac 1d,$ with equality only when $c=d.$